# Flush /tmp during MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, flush, tmp

I have a query running on a large table that worked when I did limit 100. When I remove the limit I get:

> [Err] 126 - Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_5e2d_6.MYI'; try
>   to repair it

I checked with server admin basically the `/tmp` file fills up quickly.

Is there a way to set up the query to flush the table as it goes along? Or run say 100 records, stop, re-run?  The query is pretty simple:

```
select distinct a, 
       min(b)   N_b
from K
group by a;
```

At the end of the day what I am trying to do is delete from a large table duplicate records, keeping the record with the lowest value in `b`. This was the initial `select` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like,
*** Edit according to the language you use.

```
$sql = true;
int i = 0;

While($sql){

$sql = "select distinct a, 
       min(b)   N_b
from K
group by a LIMIT i, i+99";
//Do whatever you want.
i=i+100;
}
```